# Can i use 2 different indexes on a fulltext search?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

i'm not very very experimented with the indexes so that's why i'm asking this silly question. i searched like everywhere but i didn't get a clear answer.

I will have a table `items` with columns: `id`,`name`,`category`,`price`

**Here will be 3 indexes:**

1. `id` - Primary Index
2. `name` - FullText Index
3. `category,price` - Composite Index

I estimate my table in future will get like 700.000-1.000.00 rows.

I need to do a `fulltext` search for `name` and where `category` is a specified category and order by `price`.

So my query will be this:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST(‘my search’) and category='my category' order by price
```

**My question is: 
How many index will be used to perform this search?**

It will use 2 indexes?

**[fulltext index] & [category,price] index** - *Will get results for words and then will use the next index to match my `category` and `price` order*

It will use 1 index

**[fulltext index] only** - *Will get results for words, but after will have to manually match my `category` and `price` order*

I want my query to be fast, what are you opinions? I know the `fulltext search` is fast, but what happen if i apply clauses like: category and price order? will be same fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL will only ever use one index in any search. The reason being that using two indexes will require two searches. This will make the query much more slower. You can force MySQL to use a specific index in a query but this is not a good idea.

In summary: MySQL will only ever use one index it cant use two indexes.

Comment: If will use only 1 index, will not be slow to match out the category and price after?

Comment: Not as slow as executing two queries. A million records is very very small. So i would not worry about it.